# ¿Cómo puedo mejorar los tiempos de ejecución de esta función de evaluación de un algoritmo genético usando Cython?

Tags: python, cython

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un algoritmo genetico, y me gustaria mejorar mi función de evaluación ya que no sé que más puedo hacer para mejorar la velocidad de ejecución.

Estoy mas que nada buscando cambios faciles en mi codigo, cosas que no estoy viendo o que podrian mejorarse. Si necesitan más detalles por favor haganmelo saber, esta es la primera vez que publico algo en stackoverflow. Actualmente trabajo en un Jupyter notebook, no sé si eso afecte también.

For ejemplo: Estaba pensando sobre usar numpy.arrays en vez de usar listas de python. O quizas simplemente no estoy usando correctamente Cython.

```
%%cython -a

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp # Import for NumPY C-API
cimport cython


@cython.wraparound(False)

@cython.boundscheck(False)

@cython.cdivision(True)

def fitness_function(cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim=2] x, int np_ext, int np_int, float m_l, float m_i, cnp.ndarray m_ext, cnp.ndarray[cnp.double_t, ndim=2] m_int):

cdef double G = 0.00000000006674, r_norm
cdef float a_sh, e_i_mean
cdef int j, k, factor = 1000
cdef cnp.ndarray r_tp, r_i, r, a_mascon_coord
cdef list a_m, e_i, J
cdef long int[:] i

J = []


for i in x:   #Decision vector   

    e_i = []

    for j in range(0, np_ext): 

        a_m = [] 

        r_tp = m_ext[j][0]

        a_sh = m_ext[j][1]

        for k in i:
                # [x1,x2,x3]

                r_i=m_int[k-1]

                r=(r_tp-r_i)*factor
                r_norm = np.linalg.norm(r) 

                a_mascon_coord = -((G * m_i)/(r_norm)**3) * r 

                a_m.append(np.linalg.norm(a_mascon_coord))

        #Compute error
        e_i.append(abs(sum(a_m) - a_sh))

    e_i_mean = np.mean(e_i)

    J.append(e_i_mean)

return np.array(J)
```

Comment: Traduce por favor

Comment: Hi, this is [es.so], please translate your question to Spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Thanks

Comment: Listo. Una disculpa.

Comment: @MauricioContreras debería crear una pregunta nueva o basta con que este traducida?

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo mejorar el tiempo de ejecución de esta función de evaluación de un algoritmo genético usando Cython?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/351814/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-mejorar-el-tiempo-de-ejecuci%c3%b3n-de-esta-funci%c3%b3n-de-evaluaci%c3%b3n-de-un-a)