# ¿Cómo puedo mejorar el tiempo de ejecución de esta función de evaluación de un algoritmo genético usando Cython?

Tags: python, cython

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un algoritmo genético, y me gustaría mejorar mi función de evaluación ya que no sé que más puedo hacer para mejorar la velocidad de ejecución.

Estoy mas que nada buscando cambios fáciles en mi codigo, cosas que no estoy viendo o que podrían mejorarse. Si necesitan más detalles por favor haganmelo saber, esta es la primera vez que publico algo en stackoverflow. Actualmente trabajo en un Jupyter notebook, no sé si eso afecte también.

For ejemplo: Estaba pensando sobre usar numpy.arrays en vez de usar listas de python. O quizas simplemente no estoy usando correctamente Cython.

```
%%cython -a

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp # Import for NumPY C-API
cimport cython


@cython.wraparound(False)

@cython.boundscheck(False)

@cython.cdivision(True)

def fitness_function(cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim=2] x, int np_ext, int np_int, float m_l, float m_i, cnp.ndarray m_ext, cnp.ndarray[cnp.double_t, ndim=2] m_int):

    cdef double G = 0.00000000006674, r_norm
    cdef float a_sh, e_i_mean
    cdef int j, k, factor = 1000
    cdef cnp.ndarray r_tp, r_i, r, a_mascon_coord
    cdef list a_m, e_i, J
    cdef long int[:] i

    J = []


    for i in x:   #Decision vector   

        e_i = []

        for j in range(0, np_ext): 

            a_m = [] 

            r_tp = m_ext[j][0]

            a_sh = m_ext[j][1]

            for k in i:
                # [x1,x2,x3]

                r_i=m_int[k-1]

                r=(r_tp-r_i)*factor

                r_norm = np.linalg.norm(r) 

                a_mascon_coord = -((G * m_i)/(r_norm)**3) * r 

                a_m.append(np.linalg.norm(a_mascon_coord))

            #Compute error
            e_i.append(abs(sum(a_m) - a_sh))

        e_i_mean = np.mean(e_i)

        J.append(e_i_mean)

    return np.array(J)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo mejorar los tiempos de ejecución de esta función de evaluación de un algoritmo genético usando Cython?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/351424/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-mejorar-los-tiempos-de-ejecuci%c3%b3n-de-esta-funci%c3%b3n-de-evaluaci%c3%b3n-de-un)